# javascript get callback from method

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I'm using the [cameratag js library](https://cameratag.com/docs/camera_methods) functions and am wondering how I get the [callback response](https://cameratag.com/docs/app_advanced#callback) from them (for example the publish() function). Similar to how you would get the response from an ajax call. I'm pretty novice at javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is not javascript or jquery, that response will be sent to your server after you upload a video, you will receive a **POST request to a specified URL in YOUR server** which will include that JSON inside the request body. What you have to do is to parse the JSON and process it in your server function, for example, save the info in your database